# SQL Date format

Tags: sql-server

How I can convert **1/6/2011 12:00:00 AM**  to  **01/06/2011** in MS SQL?

Comment: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/configuration/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-date-time-to-just-date-.aspx
A similar discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to compare two datetime based only on date, this should help

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

In Sql Server 2008 there is also the type [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) so a

```
CAST(@date as DATE)
```

should work too.
For example this code

```
declare @dt as datetime
declare @d as date

set @dt = getdate()
set @d = cast(@dt as date)

print @dt
print @d
```

Has this output

```
mar 31 2011 11:46AM
2011-03-31
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use Format 103](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Great, works also for yyyy-mm-dd using substring(convert(varchar, crdate, 121), 1, 10)

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(char(10),aDate,101);
```

Does it work for your question?

Edit: if '1/6/2011 12:00:00 AM' is a string.

```
declare @aDate datetime;
set @aDate = '1/6/2011 12:00:00 AM';
print convert(char(10),@aDate,101);
```

Comment: @Remya:Just update a new solution for the case that '1/6/2011 12:00:00 AM' is a string.